# Trouble trapping Python network share exception with Raspistill and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

Please help me wrap my brain around handling an exception when using subprocess in the following scenario. I am sure many of you could come up with some really advanced exception traps but I am really looking for rudimentary knowledge so I can build on that over time. This code is writing a jpeg image to a mounted windows network share. I have purposely toggled Read/Write permissions on the share, basically denying the Pi access. I don't want my program to spew it's digital guts in the absence of a good storage location, but rather just pass me a sensible message.

```
    snap_pic = 'raspistill -t 1200 -a '+pic_tag+' -ae 50,0x00,0x8080FF -o '+file_path
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(snap_pic, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            print ( 'Cannot write to network storage' )
            sys.exc_clear()
        else:
            print ( 'Image number '+image_no+' being processed' )
```

Before this evening I did not even know what "subprocess" was and I was using os.system to call 'snap_pic'. I saw some trapping limitations with that so here I am trying to step up what little game I have. 
Should I be using .call or .check_call here? 
My "except" command always gets bypassed whether connectivity exists or not.
And should I have to clear an error flag for these lines for each iteration of this code segment?

As always, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you try passing an array instead of a string to check_call ? (e.g. ```snap_pic = ['raspistill','-t','1200', '-a',',pic_tag,'-ae','50,0x00,0x8080FF','-o',file_path]```. Additionally you find the [PiCamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/quickstart.html) Python module very useful. It's should already be on Raspian and quick start guide provides sample code to set options and take a photo. It may be cleaner/simpler thank using a subprocess. Additionally, just inc are any issues with the network, you could save locally first, then copy/move the file over the network ?

Comment: George: Thank you for that bit on information on the PiCamera python module. I was totally unaware of its existence. When I got the camera module, I simply followed some of the basic examples that the Pi Foundation had listed and I ran with that. I never thought to think that Raspistill was not optimized to be run within a Python script. I will revisit my camera code with this new camera module and then circle back around to see if I can trap exceptions more efficiently. Thanks for your help.

Comment: George: Just as a follow up, I implemented the changes using picamera and now the code works just as expected. No overly complicated code needed to trap my exceptions. And the documentation on picamera is fairly extensive; not too hard for even a novice like myself to understand. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza - I was reviewing my questions and realized that since I am so new to the forums I do not have rights to up-vote anything yet. Just did not want you to think I was not grateful for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helps. I've added the comment as an answer which you can vote and/or mark as accepted if it was helpful and addressed your query :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [PiCamera Python package](https://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/quickstart.html). It is simpler and cleaner to use compared to using subprocesses.

Here is a basic example from the documentation demonstrating how to take a photo:

```
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (1280, 720)
    camera.start_preview()
    camera.exposure_compensation = 2
    camera.exposure_mode = 'spotlight'
    camera.meter_mode = 'matrix'
    camera.image_effect = 'gpen'
    # Give the camera some time to adjust to conditions
    time.sleep(2)
    camera.capture('foo.jpg')
    camera.stop_preview()
```